# Quest Help: Diplomatic Immunity

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I'm at the point where I've retrieved my gear and had the door locked behind me.  My next task is to `Search for Information about the Dragons Returning`.

In the next room are two guards, which are easy enough to slip past, but then there's a wizard on the second floor who isn't as easy.

What am I looking for? Is it a document, a person or just eaves drop on a conversation or something? And how do I escape!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to get outside into the courtyard. I'm not sure exactly where you are, but if you are where I think you are, you should come across a hallway before going upstairs. You should find an exit there that leads you directly to the courtyard, avoiding the need to go upstairs.

Once outside, you need to get to the garden (just follow the wall of the courtyard: watch out for guards) and the solarium.

Once inside, you'll hear Rulindil talking to his subordinate. Once he leaves, head to the room to the right of where Rulindil enters (again, watch out for guards). Here, ransack the room and look for dossiers found inside of a chest. You'll also find a interrogation chamber key.

Once you have that, you need to escape. To do that, head down into the dungeon, once more dealing with the guards that you find there. You'll find a prisoner locked up as well as a chest that contains another dossier.

Finally, you'll need to speak to  and release the prisoner: Etienne Rarnis. Once freed, you'll be rushed by even more guards. They'll have the trap door key, which you can then use to escape the embassy directly from the dungeons.

> When you drop through the trap door, you'll enter a cave where you'll have to fight a troll.

After that, you're home free.

Answer (score 0):

I went all out and murdered everyone, but what you're looking for are several dossiers inside of chests.

Comment: also did the same with the prisoner just folow your arrow it will show the way.

Answer (score 0):

I found a prisioner in the basment behind a door while needs a key eather from the mage you speak of or a chest in the room upstairs.